# Is linking Search Console and Analytics as property owner by delegation possible?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

If my email ID is added as a property owner of a website in Google Search Console and if I am an admin user of the same website in Google Analytics, will I be able to link the Search Console & Analytics accounts? Because, I was getting an error message while trying to do so saying that I must have edit permissions to the property in Search Console. Doesn't making me owner by delegation also give me edit permissions?

Comment: Same problem. I think it is a bug but not sure. Even the GA account i created i keep getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These edit permissions refer to Google Analytics permissions, not Search Console permissions. Check that you have those.